# How to handle future enum values in Dart 2.17+

Tags: dart, enums

My app is connected to a custom made peripheral and draws some values from it as ints which I want to convert to enums to streamline the app code.

As the hardware evolves overtime, it is of known fact that new values will come.

In my Flutter app, I handle known values (by the time of app writing) through enum extensions, providing an 'unknown' value as follows:

```dart
// Battery live data originator protocol
enum BatteryLiveDataProtocol {
  unknown, // 0
  rs485, // 1
  ttl, // 2
  canbus, // 3
  uart, //4
 ;
}

extension BatteryLiveDataProtocolExtension on BatteryLiveDataProtocol {
  /// Build the enum out of the int number
  static BatteryLiveDataProtocol fromNumber(int number) {
    switch (number) {
      case 1:
        return ttl;
      case 2:
        return rs485;
      case 3:
        return canbus;
      case 0:
      default:
        return unknown;
    }
  }
  /// Returns the number correpsonding to the enum
  int get number {
    switch (this) {

      case rs485:
        return 1;
      case ttl:
        return 2;
      case canbus:
        return 3;
      case unknown:
      default:
        return 0;
    }
  }
```

As you can see, this code support future version in a quite handily:

```dart
const futureValue = 13;
final p = BatteryLiveDataProtocol.fromNumber(futureValue);
```

Since the introduction of Dart 2.17 (& Flutter 3) I'd like to take advantage of the enhanced enums as follows:

```dart
// Battery live data originato protocol
enum BatteryLiveDataProtocol {
  unknown(),
  rs485(1),
  ttl(2),
  canbus(3),
  uart(4),
  ;

  const BatteryLiveDataProtocol(this.value);
  final num value;
}
```

But then how can I handle future enum values?

I could do that, everywhere I want to convert the int to the enum:

```dart
BatteryLiveDataProtocol p;
try {
   const futureValue = 13;
   p = BatteryLiveDataProtocol(futureValue);
} catch(e) {
   p = BatteryLiveDataProtocol.unknown;
}
```

But this is cumbersome, isn't it? It'll be cool to have the possibility to provide the body of  `const BatteryLiveDataProtocol(this.value);` ourselves.

[UPDATE] Btw, not sure it was clear enough, but it is still possible to create a static function within the enhanced enum as follows:

```dart
  static BatteryLiveDataProtocol fromValue(int v) {
    BatteryLiveDataProtocol p;
    try {
      p = BatteryLiveDataProtocol[v];
    } catch (e) {
      p = unknown;
    }
    return p;
  }
```

And use it as follows:

```dart
const futureValue = 13;
final p = BatteryLiveDataProtocol.fromValue(futureValue);

// Makes p being set to "unknown".
```

So my question #1: is there a better/clever (aka handy) way to handle future values?

Question #2: Others language handle future enum (in Swift for example): is there a way to generate `unknown(actualValue)` as a dynamic enum value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @mmcdon20 for the factory proposal (and btw, I couldn't replace `static` by `factory` in the code below).

But one want to make sure one handle any values: values and index may be different as in the modified example I propose below where the `value` of `unknown` is now set to `-1` (`index` is `0`).

So the code has to take care of it:

```
/// Battery live data originato protocol
enum BatteryLiveDataProtocol {
  unknown(-1),
  rs485(1),
  ttl(2),
  canbus(3),
  uart(4),
  ;

  const BatteryLiveDataProtocol(this.value);
  final num value;

  factory BatteryLiveDataProtocol.fromValue(int v) =>
      values.firstWhere((x) => x.value == v, orElse: () => unknown);
}
```

Comment: It should be possible to use a `factory`, note that with a factory you need to also add a `.` between the classname and the constructor name, maybe that is why it wasn't working for you?

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right, was just a matter of syntax need to add the dot. I update the answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

> So my question #1: is there a better/clever (aka handy) way to handle future values?

I think you can improve your enum by moving the definition of `fromNumber` and `number` into the enum itself rather than as an extension.

Additionally I think you can improve the implementations of both `fromNumber` and `number`.

For `number`, enums already have a getter called [index](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-core/Enum/index.html) which returns the same value as what you want, so you can simply return the `index` in your `number` method.

For `fromNumber` we can turn it into a factory constructor, and since all enums have a static `values` list (that contains all enum values in the specific order they are defined), we can get the value we want by indexing into the `values` list. And for any invalid index we would return `unknown`.

The benefit of these changes to `number` and `fromNumber` is that you will no longer need to update these methods when you add another enum value.

The updated enum is as follows:

```dart
enum BatteryLiveDataProtocol {
  unknown, // 0
  rs485, // 1
  ttl, // 2
  canbus, // 3
  uart, //4
  ;

  factory BatteryLiveDataProtocol.fromNumber(int number) =>
      number >= values.length || number < 0 ? unknown : values[number];

  int get number => index;
}
```

> Question #2: Others language handle future enum (in Swift for example): is there a way to generate `unknown(actualValue)` as a dynamic enum value?

No, dart's enhanced enums do not work like swift enums, enums in dart are closer to java enums. Swift calls this feature [associated values](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148), but dart enums do not have this feature.